# Error executing HBASE and Pig embeded in Java

Tags: java, hbase, apache-pig

I executed this sentence en Pig and it works:

source = load 'hbase://DatosBicing'
using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
               'datos:bikes', '-loadKey true')
as (id1:int, bikes:int);

I try on to execute the same sentence in embeded Pig in java. The code is:

runMyQuery(pigServer,"hbase://DatosBicing");

pigServer.registerQuery("source = load '"+ inputFile + "' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage( " +
                            "'datos:bikes')"+
                            "as (id1:chararray,  bikes:chararray) ;");

When I execute this code,  I have the error:

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Pig script failed to parse: 
 pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[datos:bikes]'

Other parameters in Java code are:

PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");

```
   pigServer.registerJar("/usr/lib/hbase/lib/zookeeper.jar");
   pigServer.registerJar("/usr/lib/hbase/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar");
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the code below and show the result.

> pigServer.registerQuery("source = load '"+ inputFile + "' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage( " + "'datos:bikes', '-loadKey true')"+ "as (id1:chararray, bikes:chararray) ;");

Comment: Is it necessary to modify pom.xml for to work with org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage?.